# Antlr exception with message "plan b" when walking IQueryable of NHibernate entities

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've got quite weird exception when trying to materialize the `IQueryable` I got form `NHibernate.Linq`. The exception of type `Antlr.Runtime.Tree.RewriteEmptyStreamException` just states `plan b`, and nothing more. Detailed exception can be found at http://pastebin.com/kR2dvDHd

Here's the code that throws an exception:

```
var matterExtractor = new MatterExtractor();
var InactiveMatters = matterExtractor.GetMattersAtStatus(General.InactiveMatterStatus);
Assert.IsNotNull(InactiveMatters); //OK
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(InactiveMatters, typeof (IQueryable<Matter>)); // OK
var MaterializedMatters = InactiveMatters.ToList(); //Exception is thrown
```

Matter Extractor class is as simple as follwing:

```
public class MatterExtractor
{
    public virtual IQueryable<Matter> GetMattersAtStatus(MatterStatus status)
    {
        return
            (new NHibernateRepository.Repository<Matter>()).Where(
                m => m.MatterStatusHistories.OrderByDescending(msh => msh.CreateTime).FirstOrDefault().MatterStatus == status);
    }
}
```

`NHibernateRepository.Repository<T>` is an utility class that implements IQueryable via `NHibernate.LINQ` extension methods to `NHibernate.Session`. Nothing specific here, but just in case, here's the listing: http://pastebin.com/MgDxDg3Y

I don't think it's related to NHibernate mappings, since other tests that interact with `Matter` entity run just fine. Most probably it's related to the `Where` clause, but I can't understand what's going wrong with that clause. I've tried replacing

```
OrderByDescending(msh => msh.CreateTime).FirstOrDefault()
```

to

```
OrderBy(msh => msh.CreateTime).LastOrDefault()
```

but it just told me `The LastResultOperator result operator is not current supported`, so I think `NHibernate.Linq` just can't stay `LastOrDefault`.

Any ideas what does `plan b` mean and how can I workaround it?

Comment: I could repro your issue so I would say this is a bug in NHibernate, either it should generate the query or it should throw a not supported exception. You should submit a bug report. As a workaround you can evaluate your whole query on client side or reorganize your query to start with `Repository<MatterStatusHistory>`...

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that
OrderByDescending(msh => msh.CreateTime).FirstOrDefault()

Is not returning null for any elements in your repository?  That bit of code seems to me to be the bit in question.

(...OrderByDescending(msh => msh.CreateTime).FirstOrDefault() ?? someDummyStatusNotSatisfyingClause)

Might solve your problem.

Another possibility is that you haven't instructed NHibernate how/when to materialiaze the status histories in the entity definition.  My experience with NHibernate is that some query like you are attempting might be better suited as a repository function (a stored procedure)

Comment: The question was asked two years ago. Yes, I'm sure that `OrderByDescending(...)` never returned null. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the that code any more. Also, creating a stored procedure was not an option, as the app I was developing back than was a standalone addition to a much larger system; it was using main system database directly, so I was not allowed to make any schema changes.